# How to Show submit button inside text field

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a comment form where I want to show submit button inside the text field on the right side. Here is what I've done till now:

```css
.flex1 {
  display: flex;
}
.flex2 {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<form class="comment-form" method="get">
  <img src="image" alt="">
  <p class="flex1"><input type="text" class="form-control flex2" placeholder="Leave a comment..."> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">comment</button></p>
</form>
```

Using this method the form go out of screen. Is there a better way to put submit button inside text field. **Hint:** I'm using Bootstrap.

Comment: Bootstrap already has a component for doing this. [Input Group Button Addon](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons)

Comment: That code works fine on its own. Did you try it like that? Do you have other CSS that might mess it up?

Comment: @Turnip input group addon worked thanks

Answer (score 12):

Assuming you are not forced to use flexbox, here's a codepen I made achieving what you want.

http://codepen.io/habovh/pen/rLxJdM
[image]

Basically, wrap your `input` and `button` in a fixed-width relative container, and place the button using `position: absolute` on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Just add style to your button;

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" style="position: absolute;right: 0;margin-top: -34px;">comment</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**css**

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
}
button {
    position: absolute;
    left: 165px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

**html**

```
<input type="text" />
<button>Submit</button>
```

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/L7kmxkg5/)**